# Nodejs Assert not executing into Mocha tests

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, assert, mocha.js

I face a strange problem, I wrote multiple tests for my module but the last one is not working. I test an async function, everything work great, except if the test fail. I don't know why but the code after the assert.equal is not executed. If the test succeed, done is correctly called.

```
describe('download', function(){

    it('should download pictures from given URLs', function(done){
        Download.download(list, function(){

            var pictures = fs.readdirSync("exports/merge/");

            console.log('before assert - '+pictures.length);
            assert.equal(pictures.length, 3);
            console.log('before done - '+pictures.length);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

The log 'before assert' is printed, then nothing happen.
If I pictures.length equal 3, done() is correctly called.

Comment: what does the first `console.log` output for `pictures.length` ? might be `undefined` or something ..

Comment: Nope, it's an int, if it's 3, everything is ok, the bug happen when it's an int other than 3.

Comment: what message does it output?

Comment: It appear that any error that happend into this test isn't displayed and execution wait for the timeout. I don't know, scope error or anything else.

Comment: Ok, the problem come from promises into my download function. mocha can't retrieve errors as they are thrown into the promise. Will post an aswer as I foung the way to retrieve the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises swallow errors. In order for them to be thrown, the easiest solution is to end the promise chain with `.done()`.

```
    var p = Download.download(list, function(){

        var pictures = fs.readdirSync("exports/merge/");

        console.log('before assert - '+pictures.length);
        assert.equal(pictures.length, 3);
        console.log('before done - '+pictures.length);
        done();
    });
    p.done();
```

See for more information [bluebird's documentation](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#error-handling) or [Q's documentation](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#the-end) on the subject:

> When you get to the end of a chain of promises, you should either return the last promise or end the chain. Since handlers catch errors, it’s an unfortunate pattern that the exceptions can go unobserved.
>   So, either return it **or end it**.